# Is it possible in Excel VBA to read out Outlook for specific Subjects?

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

i often use your website while doin praktika for my studying. while this i have to programm VBA thingys for a company.

While this i tought it to myself and i'm pretty fine with everything so far.

My last project is a list, whith folllowing steps:

1. updates itself with new data from other workbooks (check)
2. sending out emails per  to a group of specific person with personal data in it as excel workbook (also check)
3. recieving mails with probably changed values and corrections from the group of persons. (in progress... no clue how to get there)

The last point bothers me, cause if theres a way it wont be easy to get this. The company uses Excel/ Office 2017 and Outlook.

I want to look through the Outlook application for specific Subjects. Then open the excel workbook from this mail, and correct the project's data.

i was looking arround and found some older threads which weren't working at this point anymore. Can someone answer this with "nope, not possible" or "ye, u can do it like this" :D thanks a lot fellows.

Comment: **"ye, u can do this"**.. what you have to decide is an approach which will be based on your requirements. First, how do you want to check the emails: do you want to run an Excel macro to find these emails? or do you want Outlook to prompt you everytime you get an email from this group or person? Once you have decided that, then the next step would be based on which route you want to take. I would suspect, you would want Outlook to trigger an Excel macro to update the **data** once the emails comes in?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. Well i see your structure. My boss have to do this once a week and he just wanna get sure that the projectcosts etc. are correct in his list. so he sends it to a list of projectmanagers (with one klick) who check it, maybe change it and send it back. In my opinion it would be enough to trigger everything after a buttonclick (not the most professional use but the one my boss like) just hitting 2 buttons. 1 for actuallizing data from other workbooks and send emails, and the nother button for checking the email history for a specific subject

Comment: for example ("Projectcostlist KW32") and then check emailadress from sending one and compare it with the old Projectcost data. only prob is i cant find anything for getting acces to the inbox of outlook... i found many examples but i guess its not possible anymore cause of security reasons... well my problem is that i cant find a function to watch the outlook inbox without a personal storage folder after a makrobuttonpress.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's most definitely possible. You'll need to use the "Subject" property:

For some additional documentation on this property, and examples by microsoft refer here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.subject

Here's a quick and dirty example -- you may need to debug this one, but it should get you most of the way there. This sub will show a MsgBox of the subject of an email you current have selected

```
Sub Selected_Email_Subject()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set GetCurrentItem = OutApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem


    If GetCurrentItem Is Nothing Then
            Set GetCurrentItem = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    End If


    MsgBox(GetCurrentItem.Subject)

End Sub
```

Comment: its working perfectly thanks a lot. sadly im not that into the outlook vba part. and theres no intellisense so i dont know how to change it right, when i want a specific subject. not the current or newest email subject ^.^'. how do i do that? like counting through a indexlist of mails or smth like this to check every email for the right subject. thanks guys for the fast support

Comment: There's different ways you can go about it. Two off of the top of my head would be to loop through either your active selections, or loop through all mail items in a folder. Add some coniditions into your loop to check the subject property on each loop.

Comment: If you want intellisense, instead of using **`Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`**, reference outlook in preferences

Comment: Guys very big thanks for your Tips, the intellisense thingy finaly helped me, for anyone else here is a link to a video, explaining perfectly how to import data into excel with vba: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2McAc8eXqkc best wishes